# Is this x86 assembly addressing method valid?

Tags: assembly, x86, mov, addressing

Is `mov al,31[di]` a valid instruction? If it is, what does it do?

I'm having a debate and I can't access a computer right now (my android phone is not a computer).
As you can see I'm pretty new at assembly and on Stack Overflow so sorry for any rule breaking :)

Comment: Did you make this post using telepathy?

Comment: Looks like MASM/TASM syntax. It effectively takes the byte at memory address _31+value in di register_ and moves it to the 8 bit register `al`

Comment: @Gigel, Oh, so then you _do_ have a computer. One which also makes phone-calls...

Comment: @enhzflep : I couldn't resist a bit of an edit to the question. My sense of humour sucks at 3am

Comment: @MichaelPetch - says who? Perhaps mine sucks too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `mov al, 31[di]` is valid x86 assembly in Intel syntax. It is equivalent to `mov al, byte ptr[di + 31]`.